# Oracle merge command - missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I'm trying to use the Oracle MERGE command and am getting an error saying ORA-00905: missing keyword

The query I'm trying is as follows

```
MERGE INTO vor_extract v USING
(SELECT dealer, wip_no, 
        required_date, required_time 
FROM vor_extract_temp
) t 
ON (v.dealer = t.dealer AND v.wip_no = t.wip_no)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET v.required_date = t.required_date,
    v.required_time   = t.required_time;
```

any clues anyone?

It's probably something simple as I've not used the MERGE statement before so am no doubt just missing something

Thanks all

Comment: what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: you can see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the syntax seems valid. But in case you are using oracle versions earlier than 10g, the

```
 WHEN NOT MATCHED ...
```

clause is also mandatory

Comment: ah, that will be it then. Yes I am on an old Oracle 9 DB. Thanks a lot for that. I know it would be something simple...